# Stored Procedure with input and output parameters, and select statement, not binding to datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datagridview, sqldataadapter

Here is my stored procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDailyRecon]
    @DT DATE,
    @ReviewedBy VARCHAR(20) OUTPUT,
    @ApprovedBy VARCHAR(20) OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT
    'Account 23851 Balance' AS 'Description', AccountBalance AS 'Amount'

    FROM
        ReconRecords

    WHERE RecordDate = @DT

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'Total Outstanding' AS 'Description', Outstanding

    FROM
        ReconRecords

    WHERE RecordDate = @DT

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'Future Dated Outstanding' AS 'Description', FutureOutstanding

    FROM
        ReconRecords

    WHERE RecordDate = @DT

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'Pension Check Run Prior To Deposit' AS 'Description', -PensionRun

    FROM
        ReconRecords

    WHERE RecordDate = @DT

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'Flex Batch' AS 'Description', -FlexBatch

    FROM
        ReconRecords

    WHERE RecordDate = @DT

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'TRS' AS 'Description', TRS

    FROM
        ReconRecords

    WHERE RecordDate = @DT

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'Flex Pay Percentage Checks' AS 'Description', FlexPercentage

    FROM
        ReconRecords

    WHERE RecordDate = @DT

UNION ALL

SELECT
    Description, Amount

    FROM
        ManualRecords

    WHERE
        RecordDate = @DT

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'Total' AS 'Description',
    (SELECT AccountBalance + 
            Outstanding + 
            FutureOutstanding +  
            PensionRun + 
            FlexBatch + 
            TRS +
            FlexPercentage

        FROM ReconRecords WHERE RecordDate = @DT) +

    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Amount),0) FROM ManualRecords WHERE RecordDate = @DT) AS 'Amount'

SELECT @ReviewedBy = ReviewedBy FROM ReconRecords WHERE RecordDate = @DT
SELECT @ApprovedBy = ApprovedBy FROM ReconRecords WHERE RecordDate = @DT

END



GO
```

Here is my c# code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connStr = "Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=CheckRecon;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetDailyRecon", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter DT = cmd.Parameters.Add("@DT", SqlDbType.Date);
        SqlParameter ReviewedBy = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReviewedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        SqlParameter ApprovedBy = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApprovedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        DT.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        ReviewedBy.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        ApprovedBy.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        DT.Value = new DateTime(2015, 7, 17);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;



    }
```

when i run the app the form opens and the datagridview is blank, no errors are thrown. I want the datagridview to be filled with the results of the select statement in the procedure, will have separate text boxes on the form for displaying the reviewedby and approvedby output parameters. Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: Just need to add dataGridView1.DataBind(); and it should work.  Should add conn.Close(); too.

Comment: DataBind method is not available. Also, doesn't the sqldataadapter.fill method automatically open and close my connection for me?

Comment: You could greatly improved the performance here by merging all these queries into a single query. If you really need this as rows you could use UNPIVOT. As coded your procedure selects the same row(s) over and over and over. It is horribly inefficient.

Comment: And put your connection inside a USING.

Comment: would love to make my stored procedure better using unpivot, can you show me what that would look like please? I'm a tsql beginner.

Comment: Does your query return data?
I had a similar issue with output parameters. Just to check, try to put the two lines that assigns values to output parameters before your union select.

Comment: Yes the query returns the correct data.